# Duplicate a row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (t1) with a column for FLIGHT_DATE (FLTDATE) and another column for DAYSPRIOR_TO_DEPARTURE (DAYSPRIOR), from these 2 columns I built a third column TRANSACTION_DATE which comes from subtracting FLIGHT_DATE-DAYSPRIOR, finally I have a column for bookings SUM(BOOKED).

Here is how it looks:

```
DPTDT         DAYSPRIOR    TRANSACTION_DATE    SUM(BOOKED)
01-JUN-15     0            01-JUN-15           252
01-JUN-15     1            31-MAY-15           250
01-JUN-15    -1            02-JUN-15           252
02-JUN-15     0            02-JUN-15           179
02-JUN-15     1            01-JUN-15           180
02-JUN-15    -1            03-JUN-15           178
```

The minimum DAYSPRIOR for any record (flight) is -1 so for DPTDT 01-JUN-15 the latest TRANSACTION_DATE is 02-JUN-15, saying this there is no row for DPTDT=01-JUN-15 where TRANSACTION_DATE=03-JUN-15 or greater than this date.

I want that since for DPTDT=02-JUN-15 there is a TRANSACTION_DATE=03-JUN-15 then to show a row for DPTDT=01-JUN-15 when TRANSACTION_DATE=03-JUN-15 where the records for this row should be the same to the values when DAYSPRIOR=-1 for this departure date (DPTDT=01-JUN-15).

Is this possible somehow? appreciate your suggestions on this!

Comment: Please provide sample output for what you are looking for, thanks!

Comment: you may want to improve your question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/..Question at its current form is not understandable

Comment: Hi Robert, sorry if I wasn't clear enough! So to provide a sample output of what I "would" like to get is that if I run the query "SELECT DPTDT, DAYSPRIOR, DPTDT-DAYSPRIOR AS TRANSACTION_DATE, SUM (BOOKED) FROM t1 WHERE DPTDT='01-JUN-15' AND TRANSACTION_DATE='03-JUN-15' GROUP BY DPTDT,DAYSPRIOR" then to get the same row (duplicate) where DPTDT='01-JUN-15' AND DAYSPRIOR=-1 AND TRANSACTION_DATE='02-JUN-15' (see table) as there is no row where TRANSACTION_DATE='03-JUN-15' for DPTDT='01-JUN-15' since once it gets to DAYSPRIOR=-1 then no more rows are recorded in the table t1. Hope is clear now txs

Answer (score 0):

@Sergio, your question is very (**VERY**) difficult to understand,
because your english is very.. *italian* :)

after a couple of hours of brain challenge, I think I have deciphred your thougths (not sure).

If I have understood, you want to extract sum of bookings, given a DEPARTURE_DATE and a TRANSACTION_DATE.

Your problem is that "translating" a TRANSACTION_DATE to DAYS_PRIOR, it could give you numbers less than -1

```
TRANSACTION_DATE - DEPARTURE_DATE = DAYS_PRIOR
```

so

```
'2015-06-03' - '2015-06-01' = -2
```

but you will never find any record in your t1 with:

```
DEPARTURE_DATE = '2015-06-01'
DAYS_PRIOR = -2
```

What you need is to MAP all

```
(REQUESTED_TRANSACTION_DATE - REQUESTED_DEPARTURE_DATE) < 0
```

to

```
REQUESTED_DAYS_PRIOR = -1
```

try this:

```
declare @transaction_date date = '2015-06-3'
declare @departure_date date = '2015-06-1'
declare @days_prior int = datediff(day, @transaction_date, @departure_date)    

SELECT DPTDT, DAYSPRIOR, DPTDT-DAYSPRIOR AS TRANSACTION_DATE, SUM(BOOKED) SUM_BOOKED
FROM t1 
WHERE DPTDT= @departure_date 
AND DAYSPRIOR = iif(@days_prior<0, -1, @days_prior)    
GROUP BY DPTDT,DAYSPRIOR
```

this should give your desired result

I hope this helps